# How to run each cucumber feature in a new browser instance?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

In order to eliminate dependencies and to facilitate
parallel execution between features, I want to run each feature in its own browser instance.

I currently have this setup. Would appreciate directions.

```
@CucumberOptions(..., features = "/features/"...)

public class RunCukes {
    public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

My features ...

```
Feature: Feature-1
  Scenario: A Scenario

  Give I login as "<user>"
  ...

Feature: Feature-2
  Scenario: A Scenario

  Give I login as "<user>"
```

Step definitons...

```
@Given("^I login as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void I_login_as(String user) throws Throwable {
  try {
    driver.get("url");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    //do something ( e.g.take screenshot ) and close browser
  }
}
  ...
```

Comment: I wonder why none answered this. I have the same question.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to initialize `WebDriver` for each feature, preferably in `@Before`

```
@cucumber.annotation.Before;
public void init() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@cucumber.annotation.After;
public void close() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: This would throw a problem when re-using the step `Give I login as "<user>"` because variable `driver` would be undefined, isn't?

Comment: You also use so called `tagged hooks` which will allow you to make custom `@Before` and `@After` - http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/